# Adding Sound on Button Click Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

So I have a scenario in my text based adventure that I'm trying to add a sound effect to when a certain player choice is made but I'm having trouble adding it.

```
<html> 
  <div id="s1">
    <div class="sit_2">
      You  stumble upon a dark cave. Do you go inside or not?               
    </div>
    <div class="sit_3a">
      A hungry bear comes and kills you.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="q1">
    <input type="button" class="choice_2a" value="Go inside">
    <input type="button" class="choice_2b" value="Don't go inside">
  </div>
  <audio id="bear" preload="auto" src ="audio/bear.mp3"></audio>    
</html>


<javascript type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".choice_2a").click(function(){
      $(".sit_2, .choice_2a, .choice_2b").hide();
      $("#cave").fadeOut(3000);
      $(".sit_3a").fadeIn(3000);
      $("#bear").play();
    });
  )}
</javascript>
```

So what I'm trying to do is play #bear when .choice_2a is selected using jQuery.

Comment: `<javascript>` should be `<script type="text/javascript">`. Also be sure to include the jQuery library

Comment: I hope that this isn't your complete HTML. You'll need a doctype, a head and body element. `script` tags instead of javascript, and that should be inside the html tags.

Comment: @BramVanroy Thank you for the help, no that was not all of my html, I left out those elements by mistake. I do have all of that and the code does work as I have it, though my music is not playing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<javascript>` tag, you need to use the `<script>` tag instead. It should look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

But even better, it would be best to reference the JavaScript in another file altogether to provide cleaner, more modular code.

Also, make sure you have jQuery included. From the code snippet, it seemed to be missing.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("#my-audio").play()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<javascript>` code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".choice_2a").click(function(){
            $(".sit_2, .choice_2a, .choice_2b").hide();
            $("#cave").fadeOut(3000);
            $(".sit_3a").fadeIn(3000);
            $("#bear").play();
        });
    )};

</script>
```

And make sure that you have included jQuery library in your `<head>` tag, something like: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">`